# Disable soft keyboard when using ViewFlipper

Tags: android, viewflipper

I am using `ViewFlipper` to swipe through different layouts each having their own EditText boxes. When I swipe to next/previous child, the soft keyboard automatically pops up even if I disabled using `android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden"` for the activity in the manifest file. 
I want to disable the automatic popping up of the soft keyboard and make it appear only if the user clicks on EditText box. Can somebody help?

Answer (score 1):

Solved it by including
`android:focusableInTouchMode="true"` in the parent `LinearLayout` of each child.